# Can I subscribe to the opener window's load event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In a child window I need to wait for the opener window to navigate to another domain (or to be closed). I am currently not using events but using an interval to check the opener window until either the opener window is null or I can no longer access its location (due to cross domain restriction). I want to try to use an event in the opener window instead.

This is how I open the child window:

```
window.open("wait.html", "_popup", "");
```

This is how I am trying to subscribe to the event in wait.html:

```
window.opener.addEventListener('load', waiting, false);
function waiting() {
    console.log("Waiting...");
}
```

But the event handler is not called. I am working in Chrome, so `addEventListener` should work here right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a document loads all javascript and events are cleared, this is for security reasons and there should not be away around this.

One way of achieving similar behavior is to subscribe to the unload event.

Comment: But after the first unload has happened, the unload handler is also cleared, right?

Comment: Yes, once the user has left pages you control, you can no longer control the user.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be to call a function in the child:

```
var AWindow; 
function openChild() 
{ 
   AWindow = window.open("TestCallBack.html"); 
};
```

and in your parent window event handler:

```
var myChildSays = AWindow.childCallBack('from parent');
```

and a function in the child window:

```
function childCallBack(passstuff) 
{ 
  return "CHILD GOT:(" + passstuff + ")"; 
};
```

Comment: Well, technically that is not subscribing to the parent window event from the child window. Is that not possible?